# import only selected functions from numpy / reduce size of pyinstaller result

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, pyinstaller, exe

I created a code which includes several packages. Now I want to create an .exe File by using pyinstaller. Everything works fine, but the result file has a size of 175MB (already using GPX compressing). Importig numpy and matplotlib increases the size of the outputfile ~170MB, althoug I only use a few functions from numpy and matplotlib. Is there a way to only import selected functions from both packages (from ... import ... did not had any effect)? or are there some alternative packages?

Comment: What do you mean by selected functions?  If you've created a numpy array, all of the classes methods, much of it compiled, is being 'used'.  Nuumpy functions mostly reference those methods, and are a minor part of the load.

Comment: I only use functions shape, ceil, floor, round, load, save, zeros, diff, sqrt, array, arange, hstack, vstack, argmin, abs, cumsum, max, pi, sin, cos. When I create a exe file without numpy, it has a size of 8MB, with numpy more than 170MB. Is there any way to reduce this size?